# How do I say "full of obstacles" with one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

> ...paving the [full of obstacles] way to fluency.

Is there a one-word adjective I can use to replace that outrageous 3-word one?

I swear I've heard of it somewhere, but I've been searching for it for almost an hour now, and have come no closer to success than when I began.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the phrase the desired word is going to be inserted into is a metaphor about paving a road, perhaps "**rocky**" will serve.  This sense of the word is defined by oxforddictionaries.com as

> Difficult and full of problems

Comment: As it happens, there are a couple of written references to [*pave the rocky road*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pave+the+rocky+road%22). But I don't think the metaphoric usage works very well, because paving slabs are really just rocks anyway (of the right size and shape, in the right positions). In principle I suppose you could pave a rocky road by simply cutting and moving around those rocks that are creating the uneven surface, but I think OP is just trying to cram too much into one clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wedded to "paving", @DougWarrn's suggestion of "rocky way" would work. If not, you might want to consider:

> "navigating the obstacles to fluency"
>
> OR
>
> "clearing the hurdles to fluency"
>
> OR
>
> "overcoming the pitfalls to fluency"

There are many possible word choices.

From M-W:

> [*hurdle*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hurdle):
>   something that makes an achievement difficult
>
> [*pitfall*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitfall): a
>   danger or problem that is hidden or not obvious at first

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for the word 'hindered'. According to dictionary.com when it can mean (when used without an object):

> to be an obstacle or impediment.

To use it in your sentence I would more likely use the opposite:

> ...paving the *unhindered* way to fluency.

which implies that the path paved will be free of obstacles and impediments.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, ***thorny*** works here. A **thorny** way is  a way full of *difficulties* (synonym of *obstacles*).

> ...paving the ***thorny*** way to fluency.

M-W:

> **thorny**
>   *[adjective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thorny)*
>   **2** :  full of difficulties or controversial points :  ticklish
>
> stay out of the thorny brambles unless you want a ton of scratches

**Usage examples**:
[Google search for "thorny way"](https://www.google.com/search?q=thorny%20way)